# Android Wear access external storage and SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, store

is there any possibility to access the external storage from my Wear App?

My Handheld App downloads Texts and Pictures and stores Texts in SharedPrefs and Bitmaps in the external storage.

If the only way is through the GoogleApiClient, how can I use this way to get the data at any time, not through onDataChanged?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand, you want to access to the external storage of you handheld device from the wearable ?

Comment: You can't directly, your wear app have to send a message to the handled to ask for some assets ou sharedPreferences.

Comment: @pdegand59 ok, thanks. Do you know any tutorial besides the code snippets form Android Developer for my case?

Comment: You can use the MessageAPI (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi.html) to request the file listing from the handheld. Then either you send it back as a String that you parse when received, or through an Asset with the DataAPI (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/DataApi.html).

Comment: Solved it with your suggestion (wear->WearableListenerService on Handheld->wear), if you can put it as answer I can accept it.

Comment: How do you save any in SharedPrefs in Wear service?

Comment: I don't...I'm storing neccessary data on the handheld and if the wear app is called I'm asking for my data from the handheld through WearableListenerService